# Is there a way to download all the maven dependencies separately and then import them locally

Tags: maven

I am suffering the slow download of maven.

I use the default configuration for Spring Boot starter project.

```
Group: com.example
Artifact: Demo
```

[image]

STS takes too much time to sync the content. is there a way to speed this up? for example, download the whole thing separately that the project needs, and then import them locally.

Comment: `cd to the directly that has POM` and then execute `mvn clean package`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Does "clean package" mean clear all dependencies?

Comment: Do not build the first time inside an IDE in particular in Eclipse; please build the first time on plain command line that's much faster...

Comment: Does building the starter project on plain command line would skip those dependencies?

Comment: @czlsws yes. `clean` cleans your target directory. and to find out what package phase exactly executes: `mvn help:describe -Dcmd=package`

Comment: It will skip the download of needed dependencies if they are not in your local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository`. If they are already there they will not being downloaded again...

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully at the screenshot you'll notice that it says that Maven download operation is blocked by user operation.

The comments saying the build is slower under IDE (particularly Eclipse) are wrong in the sense that they are sort of a mental shortcuts. They are based on observation (it may indeed take longer time to achieve the end result) but that does not mean the build/download itself is slower. The thing is that Eclipse performs way more operations than just the build alone and sometimes those end up waiting on one another (as your screenshot clearly indicates).

With that in mind, if you run your build on the command line it may complete a lot faster as most likely it will not compete for resources with other tasks. But keep in mind that will keep Eclipse out of sync with what is actually on the file system. Eventually Eclipse will figure that out and try to sync. Sometimes it may not and you would have to do it manually. In both cases, depending on the size and amount of the projects and the number and complexity of changes made, it may take significant time to sync.

To summarize, it's not "slow download of maven" what you experience but multiple tasks competing for resources and waiting on each other. There is no point to pre-download all dependencies as this is not a recurring operation. Maven ONLY downloads missing dependencies. Once they are in local repo it will not try to download them again (unless you force it to).

Comment: There are performance improvements in newer Eclipse versions, so make sure to use the latest Eclipse (see also [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.10/jdt.php#null-scheduling-rule)).